# Nginx with default_server and multiple domains on one ipaddress

Tags: nginx

i have just freshly installed nginx and created a new configuration for test.example.com.
Which works.

But also example.org points to my server. Now if I go to example.org nginx redirects me to test.example.com.

I've read that you need to create a default server entry and e.g. return 444;
Which is what I did. 
This is my configuration for the site:

```
server {
    listen       IP:80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /nowhere;
    rewrite ^ https://test.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
    listen IP:443;
    server_name test.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root [...];

[...]
}
```

The default server entry I added in the nginx.conf before (also tried after) "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;"

```
server {
    # use default instead for nginx 0.7.x, default_server for 0.8.x+
    listen IP:80 default_server;      

    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

For me this looks correct. But I still get redirected from example.org to test.example.com.

Comment: Since this is not programming related, it is offtopic for here. It is better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a server_name set at all in the default one. It does need to be before your actual server block in the nginx config.

Also 444 is a weird error to return. You should just return a 404 to indicate that the server is not found, rather than the custom Nginx error code.

**Edit**

As for the SSL not working, you don't appear to have actually set the SSL certificates in your config file or turned ssl on.

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;  

    server_name test.example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root [...];
}
```

Comment: You will need to show your whole config. The smaples provided don't say very much.